# Using google cloud storage and gsutil not able to generate valid signedurl

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have been trying  to create a signedurl using gsutil of google cloud storage, I have been using python from my windows machine
Till now what I have done is

- Created a service account from google's developer console
- Then from my python I have executed this command to configure service account "gsutil config -e"
- Then given my credential information as asked by the console
- Then I tried to create a signed url for one of my object using following command
- python gsutil signurl -d 10m -p notasecret p12file.p12 gs://{my bucket}/{my object}
- This gave me this output with error message

https://storage.googleapis.com/support-videos/a.txt?GoogleAccessId=myaccessid@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1409209504&Signature=GI5Uo8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4hHzPqq1c%3D

myaccessid@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have permissions on gs://{my bucket}/{my object} using this link will likely result in a 403 error until at least READ permissions are granted

I have given read permission to all users on object

Please, Help me out of this, I have been stuck on this for 2 days...

Comment: Is your long-term plan to restrict access to the object without a signed URL? If anonymous user have read access to the object, there's no reason you need to use signed URLs at all.

Comment: Also, followup question, does the generated URL work correctly?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough 
Yah, I want to restrict other users to have that file, I just want to create authenticated url for few minutes for users only, No generated url doesn't work it shows signdoesnotmatch error

Comment: Is there any possible problem with configuration of boto file in  gsutil?

**When I configure Service account I give**
`
1) First Command python gsutil -a
2) What is your service account email address? myaddress@developer.gserviceaccount.com
3) What is the full path to your private key file? C:\gsutil\asdasd-f7169643abf6.p12
4) What is the password for your service key file [if you haven't set oneexplicitly, leave this line blank]? <Empty>
5) What is your project-id? my project id
`

Comment: I also tried this with google-api-php-client and I wasn't succeed with it aswell ... Help me out this ... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608150/using-google-api-php-client-not-able-to-create-proper-signedurl

Comment: For More information see this image of my command line execution 
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2uhlqgp.jpg

Comment: Quick question: is it possible that the service account associated with this object really does not have read access to this object? To verify, you could configure gsutil to run as your service account with "gsutil config -e" (warning: back up your .boto file first, or you'll have to re-configure gsutil as yourself later).

Comment: Yahh, this command runs completely properly, See http://oi57.tinypic.com/o7vbpf.jpg

Comment: I am facing this problem with space in file name
I am using this python command
python gsutil signurl -d 10m -p notasecret key.p12 "gs://bucket/File name with space check.txt" 
and it is giving me "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error 
<StringToSign>
/buckethha/File%20name%20with%20space%20check.txt
</StringToSign>

Comment: Interesting. I think you have discovered a gsutil bug. I will file it in the appropriate place. For now, can you try replacing the space with a %20 in the command line, as in the following and let me know if it works?  `gsutil signurl key.p12 gs://bucket/File%20name%20with%20spaces.txt`

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Nope that doesn't work, and it even doesn't show any error message, it just shows empty white browser page ... No XML Error Response –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I was trying to access has spaces in its name due to some bugs with urlencoding I wasn't able to create proper url for it ...

So for files without spaces works fine with me

Reference -> [Using google cloud storage and gsutil not able to generate valid signedurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562798/using-google-cloud-storage-and-gsutil-not-able-to-generate-valid-signedurl?s=01a186e1-58f9-4eaf-be1b-0b81edbb7b30#comment40120111_25562798)