# Not able to upload files with space in the name

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am not able to upload the file which has space in file name to google cloud storage, I am able to upload file names without spaces

**Here is my php code**

```
set_include_path("../google-api-php-client-master/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once "Google/Signer/P12.php";
require_once "Google/Utils.php";
/**
 * Create a signed URL to access the named resource at the cloud
 * storage facility. Right now, this is Google Cloud Storage. The
 * URL will be returned to the client, which uses Cross-Origin Resource
 * Sharing (CORS) to access the file directly.
 */
function storageURL($fileName, $method = 'GET', $content_type = "", $duration = 10 ) {
    $expires = time( ) + $duration*60;
    $to_sign = ($method . "\n" .
                /* Content-MD5 */ "\n" .
                $content_type . "\n" .
                $expires . "\n" .
                '/bucketname/' . $fileName);
    $signature = '*Signature will go here*';


    $signer = new Google_Signer_P12(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/'."final.p12"), "notasecret");
    $signature = $signer->sign($to_sign);

    //$signature = Google_Utils::urlSafeB64Encode($signature); // This doesn't work somehow
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

    return ('https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/' . $fileName .
            '?GoogleAccessId=' . 'serviceaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com' .
            '&Expires=' . $expires . '&Signature=' . $signature);
}

if(!empty($_POST["name"])){
    echo storageURL($_POST["name"], "PUT", $_POST["type"]);
}
```

Here is HTML/Javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Change handler
                $('#fileSelection').change(function(event){
                    var file = event.target.files[0];
                    var data = {'name' : file.name, 'type' : file.type}
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "signurl.php",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(result, success, response) {
                            console.log(arguments);
                            $('#sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
                            $('#sendButton').attr('uploadURL', result);
                        }
                    });
                });

                // Click handler
                $('#sendButton').click(function(){
                    $('#sendButton').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#fileSelection').prop('files')[0];
                    var file = $('#fileSelection').prop('files')[0]; // Assume a single file selection
                    if (!file) return;                // If no file, do nothing
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   // Create a new request

                    var uploadURL = $('#sendButton').attr('uploadURL');
                    xhr.open("PUT", uploadURL);
                    $('#sendButton').attr('uploadURL', "");

                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", file.size);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {// request is done
                            if (xhr.status === 200) {// successfully
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send(file);
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        Upload
        <br>
        <input id="fileSelection" type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
        <input id="sendButton" type="submit" value="Send" disabled>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also have discussed similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562798/using-google-cloud-storage-and-gsutil-not-able-to-generate-valid-signedurl/25808320#comment40120111_25562798).

**What should I do to achieve this goal?**

Comment: Have you tried URL-encoding the file name?

Comment: in php urlencode actually adds + instead of %20, so I used htmlentities for this and it didn't work, neither urlencode...

Comment: Great!!! it helped, Will check more cases now :) Thanks a lot @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function storageURL($fileName, $method = 'GET', $content_type = "", $duration = 10 ) {
    $expires = time( ) + $duration*60;
    $to_sign = ($method . "\n" .
            /* Content-MD5 */ "\n" .
            $content_type . "\n" .
            $expires . "\n" .
            '/bucketname/' . $fileName);
    $signature = '*Signature will go here*';


    $signer = new Google_Signer_P12(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/'."final.p12"), "notasecret");
    $signature = $signer->sign($to_sign);
    $signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode($signature));

    return ('https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/' . $fileName .
        '?GoogleAccessId=' . 'serviceaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com' .
        '&Expires=' . $expires . '&Signature=' . $signature);
}
```